# Why do I get serious execution lag on clicks, application switching and general usage

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, performance

I have an MBP 8.1, early 2011, 13 inch, Mountain Lion. Whenever I leave it on for more than a couple hours, I get serious execution lag on every command. For example:

I click something (a link, button, command, even a tab in the browser) and the rainbow wheel of death shows up. After a couple seconds, my command gets executed.
I click on another app, and the app does the same before warming up for use - rainbow wheel of death, couple seconds of stall, revival, work.
Text edit and preview are sickeningly slow in opening the very smallest documents, so I've had to stop using them completely - the forced version control of 10.8. is not helping in the least.
Whenever I do anything I get this rainbow wheel of death lag prior to execution, and what's interesting is the fact that

a) The CPU usage NEVER spikes above 10% (I have it on scree at all times)

b) I actually have free RAM while doing this

I can find no processes hogging up the machine, and there are no fatal errors in the console showing up.

I use it for web development, so I have the following apps open at all times: a Java (I know, death to any machine) IDE running (PhpStorm), Chrome, Sparrow for mail, Twitter client and TotalTerminal.

That's all the apps I'm running.
Any ideas?

I'm willing to try anything except sending it to an Apple store for diagnostics and service.

Edit: Additional info: This is a mint condition MBP, formatted a mere three months ago to Lion and upgraded to Mountain Lion some weeks ago. It has 4GB of RAM.

---

Final edit:
I have installed Ubuntu alongside OSX, on the same hard drive. I have also installed all the apps I use on OSX. Ubuntu FLIES, the difference is enormous. Not a single lag, in clicking, rendering, indexing, nothing. Conclusion: OSX just sucks.

Comment: How large is your page file (swap file) when this happens?

Comment: 64, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1GB, 1GB, 1GB, 1GB, 1GB, so I guess a total of 6GB

Comment: That’s not accurate. Some swap files are leftovers from the previous purge. The correct way to check for swap usage is to open Activity Monitor > System Memory. There will be a field named Swap used.

Comment: That field says 6.24GB

Comment: That’s a LOT!!! I mean seriously a LOT. My page file never exceeded 2 GB. How much RAM do you have?

Comment: 4GB, but this should not matter because I frequently have over 1GB of inactive memory. Sometimes even some free mem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4678/discussion-between-duci9y-and-swader)

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain to you how RAM works. Data is loaded into RAM first, in blocks called "pages". That is called a “Page in”. When a piece of memory is just paged in, it is in Active or Wired Memory. Wired memory is the memory used by the Core System and Active Memory is memory used by other applications.

When a page in Active Memory is no longer being used, it becomes Inactive Memory. The data still stays in RAM because an app may request it later, at which point it becomes Active Memory again.

When your RAM starts to fill up, the oldest pages in the Inactive Memory region are “Paged out”, which means that they are written to the Swap. Your system is slowing down because of this. Your RAM is full, so the system is paging out things to the disk. The disk is slower than the RAM, so your system slows down as data is paged in and out.

You must find out the app(s) using up your RAM with a combination of trial and error and using the Activity Monitor to check the memory usage of each app. Most likely, the problem is a memory leak in an app.

Comment: I see. Any best ways to approach this? I do know that Java KILLS any OSX installation, but there's no working around it, I need it to run my IDE. The thing is, when I look at activity monitor and sort by mem usage, there are no serious transgressions. Chrome is the most serious offender, followed by my IDE at 500MB, but that's it, all others are far below.

Comment: You are probably looking at RAM usage. What we want is swap usage. I am trying to find out how to do that.

Comment: Ok you have to sort by the Virtual Memory column, I think.

Comment: Yeah, Chrome and PhpStorm are definitely the worst offenders, but those are absolutely essential for my work. Still, both of them together don't exceed 2.5GB of virtual memory, that should not be such an issue.

Comment: Don’t forget the other little things. Also, I’m not sure is sorting the VMem column is the correct way to diagnose. How many tabs do you have open in Chrome?

Comment: 20 at a time, tops. That's why it uses that much memory. But again, all of those tabs are active and essential for my workflow.

Comment: You may want to look into a RAM upgrade. 4GB is really low for a development machine. There is no “problem: with your computer that you can fix. There may be no problem with your apps, except that the Java IDE might be leaking memory all over.

Comment: Indeed. But sending it to an Apple store for upgrades will take months where I live, especially if I go through official channels. Thanks though, I'll look into it. In the meanwhile, I'll wait and see if anyone else has had similar experiences in using Java apps + Chrome. This delay is the most concerning part, I can live with actual slowness, but the pause between clicks and command executions is killing me.

Comment: Performing RAM upgrades is actually pretty easy and cheap, if you find the right tools for it.

Comment: duci9y is right, you're a lot better off buying your own RAM sticks and installing them. Replacing RAM in early 2011 MBP's isn't an issue at all.

Comment: It just seems absurd, since I have a 4GB linux machine which runs the exact same software without a single problem ever encountered. I don't like being forced to buy new hardware because Apple is unable to fix their awful memory management. Oh well..

Comment: The Java IDE is to blame for the problem, not Apple. Probably it was written natively for Linux, and later ported over to OS X.

Comment: It works like a beast in Windows, too, and I have used other Java IDEs on OSX and on other platforms - always the same result. Java experiences were always the worst for me on OSX.